# SQL Server extension fails with PHP, IIS

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having difficulties getting the SQL Server extension to work with PHP on Windows Server. The installation went fine and I'm able to load `phpinfo` through the browser. However, when I enable `php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll`, it throws a `500 - Internal server error.` There are no errors logged to the PHP log.

Here are the steps I've performed:

- Followed the PHP [manual install guide](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php) and [configuring IIS to process PHP requests](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php)
- Downloaded & installed [Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)
- Downloaded & installed SQL Server Native Client (`sqlncli.msi`)
- Downloaded & installed PHP Manager and performed any recommended changes

**Enabled extensions**

[image]

**Disabled extensions**

[image]

System: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition SP1 x64

PHP: Version 5.4.10 (Thread Safety enabled)

Server API: CGI/FastCGI

Resources I've tried:

- [How to install Microsoft's SQL Server Driver for PHP](http://robsphp.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/how-to-install-microsofts-sql-server.html)
- [PHP / IIS7/ MS-SQL support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797951/php-iis7-ms-sql-support)
- [Install PHP 5.4.6 on IIS 7 to work with MS SQL 2008](http://www.deepshiftlabs.com/dev_blog/?p=1880&lang=en-us) *

`*` I have not yet tried the Web Platform Installer as I've read that it may corrupt the IIS installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had downloaded and installed **VC9 x86 Thread Safe**. After I removed it and tried  **VC9 x86 Non Thread Safe**. I also needed to download SQL Server 2012 Native Client as it contains 11.0 drivers.